# I can not figure out how to properly reverse engineer this XXTEA function

Tags: c++, c, encryption, reverse-engineering

I've been reverse-engineering an XXTea function for awhile now
And I've noticed differences but I'm unsure if these are code differences
Or compiler-generated differences from standard XXTea
https://pastebin.com/vcPKE1WR is the function
I also have the assembly, But it's PowerPC so it's a bit harder to put together.
I even have the keys and params used for the function but i'm still having issues. And files encrypted by it. And the decrypted counterparts. But not a proper function to convert them between each other.

I've tried porting the pseudocode to a C++ test directly Which did not work.
I've also tried porting the differences to a standard XXTea function for C but that also did not work.

```
#define MX(z, y, sum, key, p, e) (((z>>5^y<<2) + (y>>3^z<<4)) ^ ((sum^y) + (key[(((p&3)^e) << 2)] ^ z)))

void btea(uint32_t *v, int n, uint size, uint32_t *key) {
    uint64_t y;
    uint32_t z, sum;
    int64_t roundSizeCalc;
    unsigned p, rounds, roundsAndSum,  e;

    roundSizeCalc = size >> 2;
    if (n > 1) {          /* Coding Part, Still not modified */
        //rounds = 6 + 52 / n;
        rounds = 6 + 52 / roundSizeCalc;
        sum = 0;
        z = v[n - 1];
        do {
            sum += DELTA;
            e = (sum >> 2) & 3;
            for (p = 0; p < n - 1; p++) {
                y = v[p + 1];
                z = v[p] += MX;
            }
            y = v[0];
            z = v[n - 1] += MX;
        } while (--rounds);
    } else if (n < -1) {  /* Decoding Part */
        n = -n;
        rounds = 6 + 52 / roundSizeCalc;
        sum = rounds * DELTA;
        y = v[0];
        y = (y >> 24) | ((y << 8) & 0x00FF0000) | ((y >> 8) & 0x0000FF00) | (y << 24);
        do {
            e = (sum >> 2) & 3;
            for (p = roundSizeCalc - 1; p > 0; p--) {
            //for (p = 0; roundSizeCalc - 1 > p; p++) {
                z = v[p];
                z = (z >> 24) | ((z << 8) & 0x00FF0000) | ((z >> 8) & 0x0000FF00) | (z << 24);
                uint32_t properV = uint32_t(v[p - 1]);
                y = v[p] -= MX(z, y, sum, key, p - 1, e);
            }
            z = v[p - 1];
            y = v[0] -= MX(z, y, sum, key, p - 1, e);
            sum -= DELTA;
        } while (--rounds);
    }
}
```

When passing in properly encrypted data. It doesn't ever properly decrypt and instead ends up more corrupted. I have both the encrypted file and the decrypted counterpart from memory if needed.

Comment: Just some suggestions how to improve your chances of getting answers: Firstly, start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your code, decide on a language, then extract and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Try using the pseudocode as-is, reversing bytes when necessary (e.g. `ntohl(*(uint *)input)`). That's because PPC is BE and x86 is LE.

Comment: @rustyx I tried messing around with stuff like that. I never actually got closer to the right result. I either got further or the code just didn't work at all. The ones i do have are some of the only ones that didn't cause issues and made the math match what i could see.

Comment: Did you try to use IDA's decompiler?

Comment: I don't have the money for IDA. It doesn't matter i did eventually figure it out though. (But i don't know how to close questions if that's a thing.)